# with open(image.png,"rb") as f: in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, image, png

How to open png files like method : `with open(path+im,"rb") as f:` of python but in typescript?
If I have a folder that contain some png and i want to read and convert them to base 64 in python i use that method but which is the corrispective method in typescript?
Can sameone help me please?

I have this code in python :

```
def image_integrity():
    list_of_sha256 = []
    path = "./nft_test/"
    for im in os.listdir(path):
        with open(path+im,"rb") as f:
            f = base64.b64encode(f.read()) # read entire file as bytes
            h = hashlib.new("sha256")
            h.update(f)
            result = h.digest()
            result = base64.b64encode(result).decode("utf-8")
            print(result)
            list_of_sha256.append(result)
    return list_of_sha256
```

and I want to rewrite it in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

seems you are want read from dir.

```
fs.readFile( path.resolve(__dirname, './data.txt' ), 'utf-8', function(err, buf) 
{
    var data= buf.toString();
    console.log('load', 'OK'.green);
});
```

Comment: ok , thanks . And is there a function to convert an image to arraybuffer in typescript?